# Handle unicode in luigi

Tags: python, unicode, luigi

I have several text files which are encoded in UTF-8. I am constructing a data flow with `luigi` and what I want is to read the files one by one *into unicode strings*, clean them and finally write them into some new *UTF-8 files*. The problem is that in the `run` method of the `CleanText` class I can't seem to be able to use unicode with `luigi.LocalTarget`. Any ideas will be appreciated!

Just as a side note, I need to use unicode in order to handle accented characters in a standardized manner. Here is my code:

```
import luigi
import os
import re

class InputText(luigi.ExternalTask):
    """
    Checks which inputs exist
    """
    filename = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        """
        Outputs a single LocalTarget
        """

        # The directory containing this file
        root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) + "/"
        return luigi.LocalTarget(root + self.filename)

class CleanText(luigi.Task):
    """docstring for CleanText"""
    input_dir = luigi.Parameter()
    clean_dir = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        return [ InputText(self.input_dir + '/' + filename)
                for filename in os.listdir(self.input_dir) ]    

    def run(self):
        for inp, outp in zip(self.input(), self.output()):
            fi = inp.open('r')
            fo = outp.open('w')
            txt = fi.read().lower()#.decode('utf-8') ### <-- This doesnt work
            #txt = unicode(txt, 'utf-8') ### <-- This doesnt work either
            txt = self.clean_text(txt)
            print txt.decode('utf-8')[:100]
            print txt[:100]
            fo.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))
            fi.close()
            fo.close()

    def output(self):
        # return luigi.LocalTarget(self.clean_dir + '/' + 'prueba.txt')
        return [ luigi.LocalTarget(self.clean_dir + '/' + filename)
                for filename in os.listdir(self.input_dir) ]

    def clean_text(self, d):
        '''d debe ser un string en unicode'''
        d = re.sub(u'[^a-z0-9áéíóúñäëïöü]', ' ', d)
        d = re.sub(' +', ' ', d)
        d = re.sub(' ([^ ]{1,3} )+', ' ', d, )
        d = re.sub(' [^ ]*(.)\\1{2,}[^ ]* ', ' ', d)
        return d
```

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, what does the error look like?

Comment: There is no error. It's just that I don't know how to read from a luigi Target in a scpecific format. Any ideas?

Comment: So what happens when you try to run it with the commented out lines not commented out?

Comment: I have since changed the way I use the Targets, but the question stands. I just want to know if you can read in a format or how you should decode it, etc.

Comment: Luigi shouldn't get in the way of any encoding/decoding you do, as you don't use any of Luigi's methods to write to file.  So I think this is more a question about encoding/decoding than Luigi.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I'm kind of new to this side of python, so I'm looking at the encoding documentation ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem to write then read a unicode file with luigi.

I found this on Github https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/790 about the `MixedUnicodeBytesFormat` in the `luigi.format` module. Reading the source, I've got a `UTF8` format. You can pass a `format` parameter to a `Target` instance.

```python
import luigi
from luigi.format import UTF8

luigi.LocalTarget('/path/to/data.csv', format=UTF8)
```

This can occur in a `def output(self)` method since it's a `Target`. I think you can also use `luigi.file.LocalFileSystem` with the specific format.

Hope that helps.